# On fork() in Linux

Tags: fork

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int giCtr0;

int main(void){
int iPid;

iPid = fork();
if (iPid == 0){
    giCtr0++;
    printf("In Child\n");
    printf("Addr\t%x Value\t%d\n",&giCtr0,giCtr0);
}
else{
    giCtr0+=2;
    printf("In Parent\n");
    printf("Addr\t%x Value\t%d\n",&giCtr0,giCtr0);
}
return 0;
```

}

The output from Ubuntu is as follows:

```
In Parent
Addr    601054 Value    2
In Child
Addr    601054 Value    1
```

The Value is proper and as expected.
How does address of the variable remain same in child and parent process?
Is there anything wrong in this code? Please suggest.

Comment: That is expected.  Each process will have exactly the same contents in its address space upon fork(), but as you modify the contents in one process, Linux will provide a new page of physical memory for the region you are modifying.  That is, the memory management unit (MMU) on your CPU will cause different processes to use the same addresses to map to different regions of physical memory.

Comment: How could it possibly change? Do you think that calling `fork` somehow magically figures out every variable in the process that contains an address and changes it to contain some other value?!

Answer (score 3):

1. Memory addresses in a Unix-like VM system are per-process. The address you obtain with the C `&` operator is an OS-level construct, not the addressing scheme that maps directly to bits in RAM chips (or swapped-out VM pages). Thus, it's possible for the same address in two different processes to refer to two different locations in "real" memory.
2. `fork` spawns a clone of the parent process. For both processes to continue operating as they had before the `fork`, the entire memory image of the parent process is copied to create that of the child process... so, from each process' perspective, the memory addresses of all variables still point to the same things they did before. (But since the processes are now separate, changes in one affect a different underlying storage than is used by the other.)

Answer (score 2):

> How does address of the variable remain same in child and parent process?

To add to the comment from mkimball

Linux implements virtual memory. That means it sets up the hardware so each process sees a 'virtual' memory map instead of the 'real'/physical memory map.

Because of this the memory address `0x601054` of one process does not necessarily correspond to the same real memory 'cell' as the same address `0x601054` inside another process.

Comment: I don't think you mean this "*does not necessarily correspond*" but rather "*does never correspond*"

Comment: "Does not necessarily correspond" is correct.  Linux uses copy on write semantics to share pages between forked processes.  If a process forks, and neither the child nor the parent modifies the contents of a page of memory, the memory will be shared.  When a modification is made to a shared page, the page is then copied and the duplicate is modified, leaving the original intact.  Also, shared libraries used by multiple processes can share memory used to store the functions provided by the library.